# Узнать размер файла в Интернете

Tags: java, android

Искал по английской версии этого сайта и нашел разные методы в основном такие:

```
public long getFileSize(String string) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(string);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        return urlConnection.getContentLength();
    }
```

Но он не работает, приложение закрывается при действии этого кода.

Ошибка

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Код вызывал в `onCreatе`, чтобы проверить функцию

Может что то не так делаю? Или есть другой проверенный способ, для моей цели.
Мне нужно сравнить файл, который уже скачан с тем, что в интернете и если размеры не совпадают, то скачиваю новый файл с Интернета.

Comment: прозреваю, что вы вызываете этот код в UI-потоке, и ловите `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Вызывайте в том же `AsyncTask.doInBackground` или где вы файл качаете.

Comment: @zRrr нет, я вызывал этот код в onCreate тоже и также не успевало приложение запуститься как тут же вылетало. Хотел вывести размер в Toast при запуске приложения (проверял функцию)

Comment: @zRrr в логах смотрю есть такая ошибка которую вы написали, но этот код не стоит в потоке

Comment: этот код лезет в сеть, соотв. на него распространяются те же ограничения, что и на любой другой сетевой код. Он не будет работать в `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод, который привели вы, основан на чтении HTTP-заголовков. Конкретно этого заголовка:

```
Content-Length: N
```

Прочитав заголовки, можно отбросить сами данные, сократив таким образом время получения размера ответа в байтах. Это наилучший способ определения "размера файла".

Другое дело, что не сервер может быть настроен и таким образом, что этот заголовок не будет включаться в тело ответа сервера, и определить размер файла не удастся таким образом.

**Ваша же задача может решиться еще проще, если вы будете использовать концепцию хэш-сумм.** - Если есть такая возможность, используйте именно ее - ведь скачать 32 байта(средний размер хэша) будет куда менее проблематично, чем проверять размер файла. К слову, размер может оставаться одинаковым при расхождении некоторых значений байт, а это значит, что способ проверки целостности по размеру провалится, в то время как хэш-функция отразит любые изменения.

**Небольшой оффтоп:**

Ваш exception вызван тем, что Google надоело слышать, что "Android тормозит". Ведь сама система спроектирована так, что тормозов в ней нет. Никаких. Проблема в том, что неопытные разработчики пренебрегают многими возможностями, что приводит к появлению в GP плохих приложений, вызывающих впечатление, что "Android тормозит".
Вы как раз пренебрегли одной из таких - использованием многопоточности. Операция обращения к сетевым ресурсам - априори длительная: установить TCP рукопожатие тремя пакетами, а потом еще и массив данных передать. Поэтому в UI-потоке ее выполнять заведомо запрещено.

Comment: "*Прочитав заголовки, можно отбросить сами данные*" - то есть он GET не делает, а только HEAD? Или шлёт GET, а тело ответа читает  по явному запросу? Если второе, то это, хоть и может быть шустро для клиента, но всё равно негуманно по отношению к серверу :)

Comment: Конкретно в случае из сабжа - ни то, ни другое - такой способ соединения принимает и ответ, и заголовки вместе, так что это простой GET, из которого потом выдирается длина ответа - придется ждать загрузки файла целиком.